# Error in Flutter trying to build in Xcode: Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, runner

In Xcode, I changed the name of my app from Runner to MyApp so the Runner.xworkspace and xworkproject folders changed names too, after that I did a `pod install` and changed the names Runner in my Podfile file to MyApp and so I tried build in Xcode, the error appears:

```
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

I've already tried `pod install`, `pod update`, `delete` and `create` again and nothing helped.